# Python _winreg key path incorrect

Tags: python, registry, winreg

When I try reading a value from this key, the proper value of this key is not returned, but instead I get a different key path's value?

```
import _winreg as wreg
key = wreg.OpenKey(wreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run")
print(wreg.EnumValue(key, 0))
```

And the output:

```
('SunJavaUpdateSched', u'"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Java\\Java Update\\jusched.exe"', 1)
```

But this value is not part of the key I used? This value is not located at this key I should of got a different value.
I searched of where the value is located of the incorrect value on RegEdit and its located at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

When I use command prompt

```
REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

And I get the proper output...

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
IgfxTray    REG_SZ    "C:\Windows\system32\igfxtray.exe"
HotKeysCmds    REG_SZ    "C:\Windows\system32\hkcmd.exe"
Persistence    REG_SZ    "C:\Windows\system32\igfxpers.exe"
```

Then I would try using os.popen on python...

```
import os
buff = os.popen("REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run")
print(buff.read())
```

And the output

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
SunJavaUpdateSched    REG_SZ    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Java\Java Update\jusched.exe"
```

Why are these different? How can I get the correct value using `_winreg`?

Comment: Probably has something to do with [Alternate Registry Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) because you're running 32-bit Python on a 64-bit version of the OS. This is mentioned in the `_winreg` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html#bit-specific).

Comment: How did you set the value?

Comment: @vks These key values are auto-installed, I just want to retrieve them.

Comment: Can you try via `wreg.OpenKeyEx`

Comment: @vks Tried, same result

Answer (score 2):

> On WOW64, 32-bit applications view a registry tree that is separate from the registry tree that 64-bit applications view. Registry reflection copies specific registry keys and values between the two views.

You should disable registry [reflection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html#winreg.DisableReflectionKey).

```
_winreg.DisableReflectionKey()
# Do stuff ...
# ...
# ...
_winreg.EnableReflectionKey()
```

Comment: I tried using `.DisableReflectionKey()` with the argument of my `key` and it didn't work. I also tried it with the argument '`.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and it also did not work, they both returned the `('SunJavaUpdateSched', ...,1)` which is the 32-bit value I'm assuming.

Comment: What does _winreg.QueryReflectionKey(...) return after trying with both those arguments?